# How to select element A which parent is not B?

Tags: jquery

I would like to select an html element A which has assigned class CSS1, but it's parent is not element B. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply:

`$(':not(b) > .CSS1');`

Comment: How can I be sure that element A was selected and not for example something like element c from this: <d><c class=".CSS1"></c></d>? I would like to be sure that I have selected element A.

Comment: It's just like CSS selectors, except this works cross-browser. $(':not(b) > a.CSS1'). It sounds like you need to read up on your selectors. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html or in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/